# Conflicting plugins

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing a problem which i'm not sure is one or not. The problem is that whenever I add any plugin related to jquery star rating my sidebar does not work. The jquery plugin im using is RATY. I've also tried using JRating,Bootstrap but the result remains the same. 
This is the code for sidebar:

```
$("#content-1").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css({'left':'120px'});
});   
$("#content-1").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css({'left':"-10px"});
});
```

Please help. I have no idea why this is happening or rather this is the first time i'm seeing this. Thank You.

Comment: are you adding jQuery library more than once?

Comment: @charlietfl NoI have not repeated any plugins.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks mate. It seems i had a repeated plugin. So i created a new file for the rating function and imported it. Alls well now. Thank you once again.